# Spring MVC to SpringBoot 2: The bean 'xyz' could not be injected as a 'com..Abc' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, autowired, dynamic-proxy

I have a working project in Spring Web MVC.
Class 'A' is an abstract class. Class 'B' extends A and class 'C' extends B.
Class C has following annotations;

```
@Component
@Primary
```

Everything has been working fine until recently, we have decided to go to SpringBoot 2.
We have migrated our project to SpringBoot 2, added required dependencies.
Now, when I run the project, I get this error;

```
Bean named 'c' is expected to be of type 'com..B' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132'

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'c' could not be injected as a 'com..B' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:

Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
```

I have done some digging and found a common solution online which **does not work for me.*;
**Using any of these annotations;**

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true)
@EnableCaching.(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

P.S.
I have configuration class as given below;

```
EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@Configuration("mySpringConfig")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.allpackages" }, excludeFilters = {someExcludeFilters})
@Conditional(SomeApiSpringConfigCondition.class)
public class SomeCoreSpringConfig extends ApiWebConfiguration{
}
```

Also, SpringBoot entry point looks like below;

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SomeClasses})
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AppInitializer.class, args);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post more information about your Spring configuration and how you configured bean C.

Comment: @Javatar81 my bad! I have edited the post and added some snippet from Configuration class as well as SpringBoot entry point.

Comment: Is introducing interface `I` an option? It's usually the most effective way to work.

Comment: @chrylis, well these are classes from the JAR we are using and that JAR is maintained by another team.
Also, I wonder, why does it work with normal Spring MVC and not with SpringBoot!

Comment: where and how do you inject C into some other class?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch 

Autowired B b;

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, got it working by adding following to class "C".
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

So my class "C" looks like;

```
@Component
@Primary
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class C{}
```

However, now the error is coming for other classe. So I would say, not a sustainable solution!